# Is it normal for Windows 10 pro system to take up almost 112 GB?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, disk-space

Please see the screenshot from WinDirStat. Why does Windows 10 Professional take up almost 112GB on my 256GB SSD? Is that actually normal? I've run CCleaner and Windows' in-built clean-up tool, including for system files, but it only shrank by 1GB. What else can I do to free up disk space without affecting system performance? Thanks

[image]

Edit:
Thanks guys! From what I gather, System Volume Information is the single remaining 'culprit' after the clean-up, but I'm told that, for the sake of system restoration, that's something I shouldn't remove completely. To err on the side of caution, I've put it at 7 percent of the disk size. If there's something else I could or should do, please let me know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVjpF.png)

Comment: You are looking at your C: partition. This partition contains **all** your files and applications (usually). Windows is only contained in one subdirectory purposely named `Windows`. Look at the size of that folder.

Comment: Depends what you've got installed

Comment: So i found that the culprit might be the pagefile.sys file, as that took up some 26 GB. I went to the advanced performance settings and reduced the file's initial size to 4 GB and maximum size to 8 GB, so that freed up some 20 GB. Still, the SYSTEM (C:) takes up 92 GB now. The Windows subfolder only takes up 17.4GB.

Comment: If you want to know what’s taking up all that space, use something like WinDirStat or TreeSize. Run it as Admin for total coverage. /edit: I see that you alredy use WinDirStat. Why did you crop the screenshot? It’s absolutely meaningless this way.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did Daniel, i ran both of them and saw the figures, but didn't understand their meaning in actual practice.

Comment: 'Users' has hard links to user's data, sometimes on other disks even. They might be counted here too.

Answer (score 0):

that's because windows uses that disk for system restore points.

if u want to get that space back then right click on computer and click properties, from there go to system protection.
now click on the c drive and click configure.

now you can see how much windows is using and you can also reduce the amount that windows is allowed to store in there

Comment: The default size limit for System Protection should be 5% (12,8 GiB) with the OPs SSD.